# Exclude branches with "." at end in git svn clone

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

I'm sorry, I've tried googling for this and a dozen or so regexes but I can't figure this out for the life of me. I'm using svn2git (wrapper around "git svn" but I've tried the raw commands directly as well to no avail)

Years ago one of our scripts puked and created "tags/release-0.9." and I can't find a way to exclude this and I keep getting:

```
Found possible branch point: https://XXXX/svn/air/tags/release-0.9. => https://XXXX/svn/air/tags/latest, 1726
fatal: Not a valid object name refs/remotes/svn/tags/release-0.9.
cat-file commit refs/remotes/svn/tags/release-0.9.: command returned error: 128
```

How can I exclude this tag? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** use `git svn` for a one-time conversion. It is gread if you need to constantly sync and also commit back to SVN, but sub-optimal for a one-time conversion.

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`, but from your question I'd guess you are not using the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it's very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will easily be able to configure it for your layout to get the result you want and expect. You can also easily exclude a specific tag with the rules, or change the name of the tag to some name that is valid in Git.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of a SVN repository when migrating it to Git.